# Data type/Varchar error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012, datetimepicker, sqldatetime

I'm trying to insert in my database (SQL Server 2012) a date (dd/MM/yyyy) from a DateTimePicker. When I checked my database, the format has been saved like (yyyy/dd/MM), the problem is when I choose a day between 13 and the last day of the month, I got the message "error converting data type varchar to datetime". But if I choose a day between 01 and 12, it works.

My class is something like this:

```
public class Example
{
   private SqlDateTime date;

   public SqlDateTime date
   {
      get {return date;}
      set {date = value;}
   }
}
```

And the object that is getting my date is:

```
  Example example = new Example();
  example.date = SqlDatime.Parse(dateTimePicker.Value.Date);
```

My query just takes the (example.date) and insert it in the database. Any idea?

Thanks in advance, and sorry about my english

Comment: why are you using *SqlDateTime*, why not just simple `DateTime` and I think data type in table should be `datetime` instead of `varchar`

Comment: try to use only dateTimePicker.Value

Comment: use datetimepickervalue and DateTime

Comment: @sachin: there ARE reasons for use of SqlDateTime: here on stackoverlfow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018600/datetime-issue-in-sql-server  explains a little.

Comment: @Anderson what happens if you use example.date = dateTimePicker.Value

Comment: BDW `SqlDatime` should be `SqlDateTime` in `example.date = SqlDatime.Parse(dateTimePicker.Value.Date);`

Answer (score 0):

At least when I had this problem, I solved by formatting the date as `yyyy-MM-dd` and it solved for a Datetime field in SQL. Try this :

```
Example example = new Example();
example.date = dateTimePicker.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :
 `dateTimePicker.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`