# SqlDateTime overflow exception (yyyy-mm-dd to sqldatetime)

Tags: c#, datetime, sqldatetime, overflowexception

I'm extracting a date-formatted string (yyyy-MM-dd) and then converting it to a `DateTime` and inserting it in the database using a storedprocedure. But I keep getting

`System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.`

The column in my table is of type `date`.

I convert my string (e.g `2016-01-15`) by invoking `DateTime.ParseExact(expirationDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", null)` and then I take that value and insert it as a parameter into my StoredProcedure and execute the proc.

But when using the debugger I can see that the return value is actually a `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`-formatted DateTime.

this is an example of how the code looks like

```
string expirationDate = GetDate();
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(expirationDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);

ExecuteMyStoredProc(date);
```

Comment: @shashwat: I saw that thread but it didn't seem to be an exact replica of my problem (though I did try some of their solutions). So whoever edited my question may please remove their edit...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018600/datetime-issue-in-sql-server

See this link. It might help.

Comment: `DateTime`s don't *have* a format. They're a count of 100-nanosecond intervals since midnight on 01/01/0001. When you say "is actually a `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`-formatted DateTime." what you're actually saying is that when *something* (debugger, output window, a control, etc) converts the `DateTime` into a string, to actually display it to you, it's using some particular format. That's an artifact of whatever's performing the conversion, not something inherent to the `DateTime` value.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime convertedInitDate = DateTime.ParseExact(initDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
      cCCBEntities.initDate = convertedInitDate;
```

The code above is the code I used when I encountered this same problem that I kept on looking for like 5 hrs already. Thankfully mine got solved alright with the above code.

### Notes:

1. I was using MVC in Visual Studio to develop a web application using sql server
2. cCCCBEntities is the name of my Entity I was using
3. This answer was the answer I got above from user326608, I just cant vote on it yet so i decided to put it on a comment here to emphasize that its what it solved my problem
4. Also, even though I was using SPs when saving to DB too, I didnt have to follow his recommendation about altering the SP, if you still encounter a problem, then follow user326608 instructions about modifying your SP code

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this

```
    string expirationDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    string date = Convert.ToDateTime(expirationDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);
    ExecuteMyStoredProc(dt);
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to change the type on my column in the database? Because I can't do that. Or are you talking about some other kind of .NET DateTime object?

Comment: I am asking you to change the your database column because it will accept minimum date

Comment: I can't just change my database column, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
string expirationDate = GetDate();
string date = Convert.DateTime(expirationDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

First to get a meaningful date value in code:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(expirationDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

But, you'll still possibly get a time value in the debugger for `myDate`, as its a DateTime object.

Your SP is the next problem. Change it to something like:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyDate) Values (Convert(DateTime,@expiration_date,111)) --yyyy/mm/dd
```

The convert codes for SQL Server are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).